# Как установить драйвер Synaptic для тачпада?

Tags: ноутбук, драйвер

Тачпад Sentelic, изначально стоял драйвер Synaptic и нормально поддерживался мультитач. Сейчас тачпад работает, но без мультитача и настройки жестов, чего очень не хватает. Если есть иной способ добавить поддержку мультитача, буду также благодарен.

Подключено в PS/2 порт мыши, установленный драйвер Sentelic 9.4.9.5

Пробовал удалять драйвер, устанавливать разные версии Synaptic (одни - устанавливаются, но куда-то исчезают. Их просто нигде нет. Другие - пишут о том, что устройство Synaptic не обнаружено на машине), также пробовал ставить старую утилиту Two finger Scroll, тоже ни в какую. Также отключал обязательную проверку подписи драйверов.

Ноутбук DNS 0170717
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Answer (score 1):

Если при установке или удалении драйверов не помогает, заходим на официальный сайт производителя, скачиваем драйвер тадчпад для БИОСа и устанавливаем. Должно помочь.